# ggplot create title with superscript, bold, and with pasted variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
gtype = 'Grey'
zed = data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), y = c(1,2,3), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data = zed, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  ggtitle(paste0('MusicTM', gtype)) +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(face = 'bold')
  )
```

[image]

Is it possible to create a title for a ggplot graph that has the following:

- `TM` is a superscript to the word `Music`
- the title is bold (seems `expression()` can invalidate the plot.title theme)
- the title has the variable in `gtype` pasted into it.

Very similar to the title in the graphic above except that TM is in the superscript (given that title is already bolded, and that gtype is already pasted at end). We've tried a combination of `bquote()` and `expression()` with no success at meeting all 3 criteria.

Comment: Would `ggtitle(bquote(bold(Music^{TM}~.(gtype))))` work?

Comment: Yes I believe so. `~.(variable)` was the syntax I was missing! Thanks